# Make multiple progress bars animate when scrolled past anchor point

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

Here is my site.

http://www.colleenbowes.com/#skills

I have messed around with this a lot that I kind of gave up. I still want it to animate but I am confused as to how. All I want is for my skill bars to animate when you scroll past an anchor point.

This is my animation:

Heres whats my css animation would look like on each bar (different widths though)

```
-webkit-animation: slide 3s forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
animation: slide 3s forwards;
animation-delay: 3s;
```

@-webkit-keyframes slide {

```
from {width: 0%;}
to { width: 90%; }
```

}

@keyframes slide {

```
from {width: 0%;}
to { width: 90%; }
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var target = $("#skills").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        // do your animation
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 350);
```

Keep in mind that this is designed to run just the first time it is visible... no sure if this is expected. Also, since you do not describe your animation, I've just added the code that should detect your scrolling. If you add a bit more detail on your animation, I could extend the answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Heres whats my css animation would look like                                           -webkit-animation: slide 3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation: slide 3s forwards;
    animation-delay: 5s;


@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    
    from {width: 0%;}
    to { width: 90%; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    
    from {width: 0%;}
    to { width: 90%; }
}

Comment: do you have a class for that? if that is the case... you just need to do `.addClass` to all your `scrollbars`. I will update the answer...

Comment: I saw your site and It seems that your animation is in place already... did the answer helped you? If so... can you cast a vote for helpful :)?

Comment: Well, I have the animation on each bar so they are on each id. (i.e. htmlBar, JavaJQBar, etc...) I tried adding a class to all scrollbars but it needs an animation name, thus it needs to be specific. I could totally be going the wrong direction with this. But I need my animation to start on the anchor tag. The code you said above, I dont really understand it. I am not good with jquery or javascript.

Comment: just add a common class to all of them `.animatedProgress` and apply the animation using the class name `$('.animatedProgress').addClass('animationClass')` or if you are using jquery animate `$('.animatedProgress').animate({ // animation props });`